# mean.io $save() returning 404 file not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean.io

I am using mean.io and have come across an issue with a database collection that I don't understand.  I have a couple of lists that are similar to this and they work fine.  When I try to add an item to the Materials list, I get a 404 response from the server side and I have no idea why.

So...  Let me start with a little bit of a code dump.

Here is the Model file entries

```
var UnitSchema = new Schema({
unit: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}});
```

and...

```
var MaterialSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
unit: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Unit'
},
delivery_offset: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}});
```

So I have two basic shemas.  One is Units and the other is Materials which contains a reference to the Units collection.
This is the route file for the materials.

```
module.exports = function(Materials, app, auth, database) {
  //Setting up the materials api
  app.get('/materials', auth.requiresAdmin, materials.all);
  app.post('/materials', auth.requiresAdmin, materials.create);
  app.get('/materials/:materialId', auth.requiresAdmin, materials.show);
  app.put('/materials/:materialId', auth.requiresAdmin, materials.update);
  app.delete('/materials/:materialId', auth.requiresAdmin, materials.destroy);

  app.param('materialId', materials.material);
};
```

I suppose the next logical entry would be the server side controller's create function.

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next, id) {
  var material = new Material(req.body);
  material.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Cannot save the material of measure'
        });
    }
    res.json(material);
  });
};
```

So that's it for the server side stuff.  Now here is the client side.  Before I post, I do have a service setup for the PUT operation but this is a POST so...there's that. Here is the client side controller.
This first snippet get's called when the webpage loads.  It basically sets up the $scope variables and the ngTable.

```
$scope.init = function() {
        Materials.query({}, function(materials) {

            $scope.materials = materials;
            $scope.units = Units.query();

            var data = materials;

            $scope.tableMaterialsParams = new NGTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            },{
                total: data.length,
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    params.total(data.length);
                    var orderedData = params.sorting()?$filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()):data;
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });
        });        
    };
```

This next snippet is the add function in the client side controller that gets called when the user wants to add a new material to the list.

```
    $scope.addMaterial = function() {
        if (!$scope.materials) $scope.materials = [];

        var material = new Materials({
            name: $scope.name,
            unit: $scope.unit._id,
            delivery_offset: $scope.delivery_offset
        });

        material.$save(function(response) {
            $scope.materials.push(response);

            var data = $scope.materials;
            $scope.tableMaterialsParams.total(data.length);
            $scope.tableMaterialsParams.reload();
        });

        this.name = this.unit = this.delivery_offset = '';
    };
```

I am using ngTable for the frontend display so that is why you see some of those calls to tableBlahBlah.  It's there to update and refresh the table after the save.  Here is the form's html.

```
<form id="material-add-form" class="form-group" name="addMaterialForm" data-ng-submit="addMaterial()">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Material Name" class="form-control m-b"/>
    </span>
    <span class="col-sm-2">
      <select ng-model="unit" class="form-control m-b" 
             ng-options="obj.unit for obj in units track by obj._id">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Unit of Measure</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="col-sm-2">
      <select data-ng-model="delivery_offset" class="form-control m-b">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Delivery Offset</option>
        <option value="Two Days Prior">Two Days Prior</option>
        <option value="One Day Prior">One Day Prior</option>
        <option value="Same Day">Same Day</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">
       <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
       Add
    </button>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Any help or ideas as to what i'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  As I've stated before, I have other lists that are very similar that work just find.

Comment: sorry...shouda provided more details on the problem as well.  When I try to add I get a POST http://localhost:3000/materials 404 (Not Found) response in the browser.  I am using gulp with node in debug mode and it spits out POST /aterials 404 at the parser as well.

If i go to http://localhost:3000/materials in the browser, I get a good response with data from my materials collection.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the problem.  It was a mistake on my part which I figured.  Just not sure exactly where.  It was in the server side controller.

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next, id)
```

I am still relatively new to mean stack development so i'm not sure why this is wrong.  I changed the function definition to

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next)
```

and it works!

There was also a second problem with my implementation.  That was not in the question since I was never able to get it working with the 404 error so I never saw it.  When I saved the material item to the database, the unit (ObjectId) would not populate.  It would be blank.  I changed the save() call to this

```
material.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(500, {
        error: 'Cannot save the material'
      });
    } else {
      material.populate({
        path: 'unit',
        select: 'unit'
      }, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
      });
    }
});
```

And now it works as intended.  The resulting database entry looks something like

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5524547488842d6cb408c003"), "name" : "TESTING", "unit" : ObjectId("550f7047e9cc68da538fe46f"), "delivery_offset" : "Same Day" }

I was able to find and fix the problems but I'm a little unclear as to why it worked.